# android libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited (repeating as no solution)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-android-sdk, android-build, gradle-plugin

I am sorry for repeating same question as all solutions on net which I could try failed in to solve my problem. 
I have installed many times Linux Mint 17.2 with different Java , android SDKs, i386 libraries but all fail.

Gradle is showing warnings

```
     libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited (repeating as no solution)
```

my build script is

```
 compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
```

but when I change this to

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
```

we are using 
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
            classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.+'

changing these again making different issues.
Is this anyway to solve this issue / bug

it is working fine, but our project needs 22 for some other libraries.

Comment: The solution is to remove the offending iCCP chunk from your PNG files.  If you cannot do that or don't want to, then use libpng-1.5.x instead of libpng-1.6.x; libpng-1.6.x is less forgiving of erroneous ICC profiles.

Comment: Thanks, we made one script
`find . -iname "*.png" -exec pngfix -o -q --strip=all --out={}_stripped {} \; &&  find -name "*.png_stripped" -print0 | xargs -0 rename -f 's/\_stripped//'` and worked  fine but we don't want this solution.
I am going to try libpng-1.5x

Comment: Hi @GlennRanders-Pehrson 
can you please guide, how to setup libpng-1.5.x , on my linux mint 17.2 it shows only libpng12, libpng3. thanks

Comment: The "--strip all" option is overkill because it removes more metadata than necessary, in particular the gAMA chunk, from the PNG file.  Try "-- strip color" which will only remove the iCCP and cHRM chunks.  How to setup libpng-1.5.x is too much to explain here.  You've probably got lots of other applications that depend upon the ancient libpng12 (aka libpng3).

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson I am sorry but this solution looks not fine, as I checked on Windows 10 same warnings if clean build.

There must be some fix with Gradle or Android SDK as changind SDK 19.1.0 works fine only some other portion of project fails but this PNG issue fixes with change of SDK.

Comment: I'm not sure which solution is not fine.  You said pngfix did work for you, and I think pngfix is a better solution than downgrading libpng anyway.

Comment: You can also use ImageMagick's "convert bad.png good.png".  This will detect the bad ICC profile and will not copy it into the output file.

Comment: Thanks, I want to try libpng15, I have downloaded and install as in instruction but still  I think it is not installed. any hint ?

Comment: If your system had libpng12 and you were getting the "iCCP: not recognizing.." warning, then your application must be using its own embedded copy of libpng16.  Libpng12 does not issue that warning.

Comment: Thanks, yes I also guess same as in android SDK 19.1.0 same code and pngs have no issue and changing SDK to 20x making issue.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to open the offending .png(s) in Photoshop, do "Save to Web" (under File) and overwriting the original file.

Comment: Yeah... it really works for me too that any other, thanks for your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue because of build tools try change it from gradle

may be this help

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
  }
```

**UPDATE ANSWER**

this happen with me cause I was include PSD file into my android studio